# Why does p:poll do not start until I click a row of p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:poll` that updates a `p:dataTable` but the problem is that it **does not start updating until I click on a row** of the `p:dataTable`. When the page loads nothing happend until I click a row, after that everything works fine.

I have read about `p:poll` and have `autostart="true"` by default.

This is my `p:poll`

```
<p:poll interval="5" listener="#{adminUsuarios.actualizarLista()}" update="tblUsuarios" />
```

This is my `p:dataTable`

```
<p:dataTable id="tblUsuarios" var="us" value="#{adminUsuarios.listaUsuarios}" paginator="true" rows="50"  paginatorPosition="both" selectionMode="single" selection="#{adminUsuarios.usuarioSeleccionado}" rowKey="#{us.id_User}">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="PF('editarDialog').show()" update=":myForm:myDialog" />
    <p:column headerText="Usuario">
        <h:outputText value="#{us.id_User}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Nombre">
        <h:outputText value="#{us.nameU}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

When a row of a table is clicked I show a dialog. I think the problem could be with this stuff. Everything is in the same `h:form` and only works (the `p:poll`) after I click a row of the `p:datatable`

This is my `p:dialog`

```
<p:dialog id="myDialog" widgetVar="editarDialog" header="Editar perfil de usuario #{adminUsuarios.usuarioSeleccionado.id_User}" resizable="false" width="400" showEffect="size" hideEffect="size">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <h:outputText value="Perfil" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="cboPerfil" value="#{adminUsuarios.usuarioSeleccionado.nivelAlmacen}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="..." itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Everything is showed is the order it is in my code.

Comment: do you have your poll inside your dialog ?

Comment: Have you checked your console for any JS Errors ?

Comment: @HatemAlimam com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute /usuarios.xhtml 76,124 value="#{adminUsuarios.usuarioSeleccionado.nivelAlmacen}": Objetivo inalcanzable, 'usuarioSeleccionado' devolvió nulo javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /usuarios.xhtml 76,124 value="#{adminUsuarios.usuarioSeleccionado.nivelAlmacen}": Objetivo inalcanzable, 'usuarioSeleccionado' devolvió nulo------>So my property in selection="#{adminUsuarios.usuarioSeleccionado}" is null or the one inside the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your dialog is not dynamic and fetch it's contents on page load.
At this time no selection has been made and property #{adminUsuarios.usuarioSeleccionado} is null. That cause PropertyNotFoundException.
You can either set p:dialog componet dynamic attribute true or init usuarioSeleccionado variable before page load(for example in bean constructor).